# "Forbidden" panel icon after lock or suspend

Tags: unity, panel, system-tray

After upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10, I found that OwnCloud, Clementine and Seafile systray icons turn to "forbidden" whenever I lock the screen or go to suspend.

[image: Unity panel with forbidden icons]

They become forbidden again if I quit or restart one of the aforementioned programs (ownCloud, Clementine or Seafile), or after logging out and back in.

[image: Unity panel]

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836826/what-is-this-forbidden-icon-in-my-systray) is similar. The problem in that case was solved uninstalling a program (Klipper), which is no longer supported. The problem seems to be system-related, as it is happening as well in the session of a newly created user. How can I fix this?

**Update 23/10/16**

Removing `appmenu-qt5` fixes the panel tray icon problem of ownCloud and Seafile; their icons show as they should. However, the issue persists with Clementine.

[image: Unity panel. No Clementine icon]

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice upgrade 16.04 > 16.10

Comment: The accepted answer here should solve your problem:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/841378/status-bar-icon-indicators-disappear-when-waking-from-suspend

Comment: @SPrasanth I'm afraid the script is, in my case, neither a fix nor a workaround. It restarts the unity panel, but the Seafile, ownCloud and Clementine icons are not recreated.

Comment: Does running `killall unity-panel-service` followed by `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity/unity-panel-service &` from terminal recreate the icons.
I didn't test the script myself, I'm using a variation of it.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a very easy solution, or at least let's hope it will. Since these files seem to be "locked," it may be a permission error, so do the following. In a terminal (or nautilus) navigate to `/usr/share/applications`:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

Then either run `ls` or look around for your desired program folder. Once you have that folder, look for where the icon is stored. I will be referencing a dummy program for this tutorial.

Let's say my program is called "dummy", and the icon is located at `/usr/share/applications/dummy.desktop`. Open the desktop file, and scroll down to where the icon is stored, for example:

```
/home/users/blah/blah/icon.png
```

Switch out `user` for your name in terminal when you run the following as root:

```
sudo chown -R user:user
```

And the icon will then be saved to your permissions. Then restart and you'll be done. Another thing you could try if that doesn't work is launching the programs as root. If the program has a Terminal aspect (will explain) use that. If not, refer to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442542/how-to-run-programs-as-root-user-without-using-terminal). A terminal aspect means that the said program can be launched from terminal, for example:

```
update-manager
```

Will open the update manager app, so I would test to see if OwnCloud, Clementine, or Seafile have these aspects. If they do, for example:

```
clementine
```

Just run it as root:

```
sudo clementine
```

If that doesn't work, do let me know and I'll research some more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there are some flaws. First, under /usr/share/applications there are only .desktop files, i.e., no folders. Anyway, I copied those conflicting programs (Clementine, ownCloud & Seafile) to my .local/share/applications folder to no avail. Second, Clementine hardcodes its systray icon (so that the tiny clementine  show the song progress); so, it doesn't *seem* to be a permissions issue.

Comment: New information from research. Will update @Ludenticus

Comment: I don't think it is an icon-related issue, for this happens as well with other icon themes. Clementine can be started as root (either 'sudo' or under 'sudo su'), but it show no tray icon. http://pasteboard.co/hiCGfffv3.jpg