# Status bar icon indicators disappear when waking from suspend

Tags: unity, suspend, icons, 16.10

So, when I wake up from suspend, this happens:

[image]

The missing icons are Skype and Mega. When I close one of those programs, the other icon appear, like this:

[image]

How can I fix this or make a script that refreshes the status bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a temporary solutions until the bug is fixed, you can create a file f.e. **icons.sh** (dont't forget to give it execution rights with chmod +x) at any location:

```
#!/bin/bash

dbus-monitor --session "type=signal,interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session,member=Unlocked" | 
  while read MSG; do
    LOCK_STAT=`echo $MSG | awk '{print $NF}'`
    if [[ "$LOCK_STAT" == "member=Unlocked" ]]; then
        killall unity-panel-service
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity/unity-panel-service&
    fi
  done
```

After saving the script, open **Ubuntu Startup Applications** from Apps menu and configure this script to run after you login:

[image]

Every time you unlock the screen, unity panel service will be automatically killed and started, keeping your icons in place.

Comment: *Excellent* answer!  +10 now and tomorrow +50!!!

Comment: Works for me as well, thank you. Is this bug filed anywhere so that one could track its progress?

Comment: @SergeiMorozov It took some searching, but it appears that this is being tracked as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1628383

Comment: @joelittlejohn, thanks. From here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1635625, it looks the issue has just been fixed in yakkety.

Comment: If this is fixed, it isn't in yakkety stable (or whatever it should be called) yet. I'm on 16.10/yakkety with latest updates, and I still have the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
killall unity-panel-service
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity/unity-panel-service&
```

solves it to me, but I'm too lazy to get where to put it for autorestart on waking up. At least we know who is in charge for this :-)